# laravel, mysql transaction not working once rollback

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I am performing insertion in 4 tables simultaneously using laravel 5.8. When I Submit incomplete Form it will show me error and after that when submit proper data again it will show database error

`` SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`matrimonial_db`.`personal_details`, CONSTRAINT `personal_details_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`site_user_id`) REFERENCES `siteuser` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) (SQL: insert into `personal_details` (`site_user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (148, 2020-04-29 05:16:53, 2020-04-29 05:16:53)) ``

First time when i fill form it insert data successfully in all tables but when try again it will show me the error.
here is a code

```
try
        {
            $connection = DB::connection('mysql');
            $connection->beginTransaction();
            $userData = session()->get('registeruser_data');
            $userData->user_type = 'v';
            $userData->save();

            $personal_details= new PersonalDetail;
            $personal_details->site_user_id =$userData->id;
            $personal_details->save();

            $personal_bio= new PersonalBio;
            $personal_bio->site_user_id =$userData->id;
            $personal_bio->save();


            $partner_details= new PartnerDetail;
            $partner_details->site_user_id =$userData->id;
            $partner_details->save();

            $personal_img= new PersonalImage;
            $personal_img->site_user_id =$userData->id;
            $personal_img->save();

            $connection->commit();
            session(['siteuser' => $userData->id]);
            return redirect('/edit/profile');
            // dd($charge);

        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            $connection->rollBack();
            return redirect::back()->withErrors(['stripe'=>$ex->getMessage()]);
        }
```

Comment: before you do transaction to other table, try to print out your `$userData->id`. Is it available or not

Comment: i tried its available @Saengdaet

Comment: maybe the problem is because you don't have the `id` in your `siteuser`. like you try to insert `site_user_id = 148`, but your `siteuser` does not contain id = 148

Comment: you can see id is also showing in error message query its happen on second attempt first attempt data added successfully if i try to test with wrong input its not insert data and when again i pass proper input it shows me error mentioned above

Comment: ah pardon me, I don't notice the `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check the foreign key

$userData is a collection, since you're not looking for a specific user but you're saving the whole table registeruser_data, I recommend that you use eloquent as it would be easier

you are looking for a user like this:

```
$user = yourModelUser::find($idUser);
```

or

```
$user = yourModelUser::where('id' $idUser)->where('type', 'v')->first();
```

and then:

```
$user->type = 'n';
$user->save();
```

if you need more queries you can see oficial documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

Comment: In previous request i am saving eloquent model in session `registeruser_data`. Model is created with all registration data but i want to save it at last with other tables so `registeruser_data` is not a collection but its a eloquent model object